# Compare frequencies/proportions across groups which may overlap with one another

Tags: statistical-significance, count-data, frequency

Let's say I want to compare the recurrence rate of a house that is on fire/flooded/robbed this year will be on fire/flooded/robbed the next year in a neighborhood. My data look like this:

```
Event     Yt     Yt+1     Yt+2
------------------
On fire: 100      10        2
Flooded: 200      50        25
Robbed:  250     150        60
```

So for instance, in Yt, 100 houses are on fire; in Yt+1, 10 out of those 100 houses are on fire again; in Yt+2, 2 of those 100 houses are on fire three years in a roll.

One thing to note is a house on fire could be flooded and/or robbed. So one event is not exclusive of another. Given this kind of data, what kind of statistics should I use to test that 10 out of 100 is significantly different from 50 out of 200?

Comment: Please explain what the numbers in your data table mean.

Comment: @whuber: Thank you for your comment. I've edited my question as above. Hopefully, it's more clear now.

Comment: Thank you.  You seem to articulate two different questions.  Most of your post focuses on assessing whether a previous incident increases the chance of another incident of the same type.  But at the very end, you are comparing recurrence rates between two types of incidents.  What is the question you want to ask?

Comment: The latter-comparing the recurrence rates between two types of incidents. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your post to clarify that point.

Comment: I've edited the post. Please let me know whether it's clear now. Thanks!